# LoopBack Command Prompt is Disable After Running the Applications

Tags: loopback

I am mew to loopback . I am running the API in localhost . I created the model and I am able to access it to localhost . But the problem is I can not type anythings in command prompt windows   after running the applications ..

Here is the screen shot of the command prompt .

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you start your server you can't type anything on that console.

If you want to use console you have to either stop your server or you have to use another console.

If you want to restart your server then you have to halt it using `Ctrl + c` command and after that `npm start` command.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the same console for more commands, then open a new console and run your node server over there.

And if you want to clear your warning of "includeSubdomains" then follow these steps : 
1)Go to server/middleware.json
2)search for "includeSubdomains" key and replace with "includeSubDomains".